# How do I set up my interpreter with Pydev in Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, python, eclipse

I can't figure out what the path to my python interpreter is.  I need to know it so I can set up Pydev in eclipse on ubuntu 10.04.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Glen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL there is an "auto config" button in eclipse that magically makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
which command
```

to find where a command's binary resides.